# How to use elasticsearch filter in a search template query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a beginner in elasticsearch. I do have a search_template and I would like to use filter context to display only the result where Country is Japan for example. I tried this query in python, however the filter is not applying to the query result. Do I need to use aggregations? If so, how should I apply it

Here's my code: [my-query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2tm1.png)

Comment: Can you show the actual content of the DSL query you stored in `template-name`?

Comment: I'm sorry, how should I do it?

Comment: How did you land on this query? Please explain how one can reproduce what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

I did this example, I hope to help

Create template

```
PUT _scripts/country-filter-template
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "country": "{{country-name}}"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "params": {
      "country-name": "My query string"
    }
  }
}
```

Validate the template

```
POST _render/template
{
  "id": "country-filter-template",
  "params": {
    "country-name": "russian"
  }
}
```

Run query template

```
GET idx_country/_search/template
{
  "id": "country-filter-template",
  "params": {
    "country-name": "russian"
  }
}
```